# PHP - Create files backup using remote server (ssh2_exec)

Tags: php, ssh

I tried to create files backup of server "A", using PHP script on server "B" (remote server). I'd like to use ssh2_exec because this backup will be contain a lot of files (~1 GB) so I can't use for example file_put_contents('ftp://...', file_get_contents('/path/backup.zip')) becase I got: "fatal error allowed memory size". So I decided to use ssh2_exec, and there is my script:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('host', 222);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'nick', 'pass');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/bin/tar zcf backup.tgz public_html');
```

It doesn't work fine. I don't know how I can prepare:

- full path to files which should be zipped as backup (from server "A"),
- full path where I want to save this backup (on server "B").

The script will be starting on server "B". Anyone can help me, how I can prepare a full path, like:

```
$full_remote_path = '/home/user/domains/remote_domain.net/public_html/'; // full path to files which should be zipped, on remote server

$full_local_path = '/home/user2/domains/local_domain.net/public_html/backup/'; // full path to save zipped backup on local server
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you setup key based authentication between servers A and B and use a shell script for backing everything up? ( https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/ )

Comment: ^^ Conversly you can use a cron to back up the file say every 2 hours, and use php / ftp to simply download the file.

Comment: What @Dimi said, but with [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).